# Details of how model implemented in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

It seems to be the view and controllers are rigidly defined, but the model is highly nebulous. For instance, views go in views folder, controllers have the word controller in their name and have controller annotation, but models...?

What is the standard or de facto or at least the recommended way of implementing the model in Spring MVC and where is it located in the directory structure?

How does the model tie in with the controller? Does the model have direct access to the database? Thanks

Comment: The **Model** is *everything that is not a Controller or a View.*  That can include a Data Access Layer, a Service Layer, a Business Logic Layer, Aggregate Roots, and maybe even some DTO's and ViewModel objects.  If you want to put all that in a "Model" folder, that's as good a strategy as any.

Comment: Which of these model elements generally constitute a barebones model that interfaces with a database?

Comment: In other words what would be the bare minimum I would need to implement a model. I imagine I'd need a data access layer for sure. What else?

Comment: That's all you'd really need for a basic application.

Comment: What would be the bare minimum that wouldn't be frowned on?

Comment: Ah, c'mon.  Think for yourself!  Don't let other people do your thinking for you.  There's no value in a software developer that can't make their own decisions.

Comment: Well I don't know what the hell aggregate roots, DTOs and ViewModel objects are lol

Comment: There are plenty of books that go over that information in detail.  Aggregate Roots are discussed in Evans' Domain-Driven Design book, for example.

Comment: Do I have to know what all this stuff is just to implement a basic model that  people wouldn't frown on? I'm just looking for something that interfaces with a relational database and I wanna implement it in a way that if people looked at it they wouldn't puke.

Comment: I can't tell you what people might or might not frown on.  I don't think that way.  I do what works.  Spring MVC has a lot of this already built-in; you should probably learn more about Spring MVC.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Robert Harvey's answer "The Model is everything that is not a Controller or a View. That can include a Data Access Layer, a Service Layer, a Business Logic Layer, Aggregate Roots, and maybe even some DTO's and ViewModel objects. If you want to put all that in a "Model" folder, that's as good a strategy as any."